# const os = require('os') SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode

Tags: javascript, teamcity-9.0

While building application with Teamcity 9.1.7 we are getting below error -

> > const os = require('os');
> >     ^^^^^

Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR

> > SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.

Any help is greatly appriciated

Answer (score 0):

add `'use strict';` to the top of the file. Or better update your node.js

```
'use strict';
const os = require('os');
// rest of the file
```

For your version of node (6.11.3 as you've mentioned in comment) everything should works fine. I've just checked

[image]

Comment: We are already using 'use strict' at the top of the file. And we have node version 6.11.3 and npm 3.10.9

Comment: @KrishnaKumarChourasiya could you show full file?  https://monosnap.com/file/9iuvhykqhUkhgyzIEayX9ArNsIc4Fg I've just tested at the same version of node and everything works fine, even without that string. Please show output on your node version

Comment: There is teamcity job which build our application with node npm and yarn supports. During building the application in node_modules/supports-color/index.js at line2, having this code which is creating problem that I can't modify.

Comment: @KrishnaKumarChourasiya still waiting for certain and correct node version